# Why does f_print not work correctly on SD card?

Tags: c, file, intel, sd-card, fatfs

Currently, I am working on writing to an SD card with Intel D2000 Quark board. I am using the standard FatFs system to set up a FAT16 standard.

The problem:
Whenever I write to the SD card, the SD card saves it only when there is something on the file. This means, the text I am sending, will overwrite what is in the file. When I set the read/write pointer to the end of the file(This is the goal in the end), the data I write gets lost.

My main:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    QM_PRINTF("Starting: SPI\n\n");
    FIL f;
    char text1[512] ="Ik ben makelaar in koffi, en woon op de Lauriergracht No 37.\n "
            "Het is mijn gewoonte niet, romans te schrijven, of zulke dingen, \n"
            "en het heeft dan ook lang geduurd,";
    f_mount(&FatFs, "", 0);
    fr = f_open(&f, "DATA.TXT", FA_OPEN_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
    QM_PRINTF("%d\n", (int)fr);
    QM_PRINTF("Size: %d\n", f_size(&f));
    fr = f_write(&f, text1, sizeof(text1), &bw);
    f_sync(&f);
    QM_PRINTF("write: %d count: %d\n", fr, bw);
    QM_PRINTF("Size: %d\n", f_size(&f));
    QM_PRINTF("%d\n", bw);
    fr = f_close(&f);
    f_mount(0,"",0);
    QM_PRINTF("%d\n", fr);
    QM_PRINTF("Finished: SPI\n");
    QM_PRINTF("-----------------------------------\n");
}
```

The result I am getting for the console when there is something in the file and the read/write pointer is at the beginning of the file. At this point, the data gets written to the SD card and is saved (I can read it when I put the SD card in my laptop and open the file).

```
Starting: SPI

0
Size: 3362
write: 0 count: 512
Size: 3362
512
0
Finished: SPI
-----------------------------------
```

The result I get from the console when the read/write pointer is at the end of the file (FA_OPEN_APPEND):

```
Starting: SPI

0
Size: 3362
write: 0 count: 512
Size: 3874
512
0
Finished: SPI
-----------------------------------
```

After this, when I put the SD card in my laptop, the text is gone.

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution. When you need more information, please ask.

Comment: Opening files for writing only usually truncates the file (removes the existing data) on most systems. Same thing happens with the standard C `fopen` function when you open using `"w"`.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude It doesn't work with only write or with both read and write.